# Photo Competition 2020-02-01: Imperfectly Beautiful

Tags: photo-competition

#### Theme

This theme challenges you to find beauty in unexpected places. Appreciating it not only in spite of imperfections, but perhaps even because of them.

#### Voting Rules

- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on February 14, 2020 at 12:00 AM UTC**. The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Multiple entries are encouraged, but please don't spam answers. The aim is quality over quantity.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date.**
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

- Suggest a theme for the next contest. Leave a single comment below in the format,

  > Theme: <*one sentence description*>
- Upvote the comment(s) with the theme you would like to see next time.

Good luck!

Comment: This theme was suggested by @LightBender. I think it fits well with the Valentine's Day end of contest.

Comment: Of course, after V-day and this one, the logical next theme would be complimentary/mutually completing/juxtaposed things :)

Comment: Great to see all the contributions. Should there be a size restriction or guidance beyond the 2MiB limit from uploading? In terms of pixels how big should an image be? I ask because I feel my portrait oriented picture takes up a lot of screen space. It uploaded at it's full 10MB due to all that white compressing heavily but I reduced it to 1080 pixels on the shortest side and it's still huge due to the orientation.

Comment: Theme: Antici....pation

-- Dedicated to that quiet moment just before things happen.

Comment: @LightBender nice...

Comment: Congratulations to @rackandboneman for winning this contest. And thank you to all submitters, this was a fun contest to vote on!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

Razor Wire, Wiesbaden, Feb 4, 2020

Note: Looks like selective color when viewed at a small size. None applied. Just odd, found lighting and camera settings happening to be a little on the weird side from previous night photography....

Comment: That is odd - but pretty darn cool too

Comment: Wiesbaden? Christ, that's halfway around the corner...

Answer (score 13):

Imperfect symmetry. Chinatown, NYC. Jan 26, 2020.
[image: Imperfect symmetry. Chinatown, NYC.]

Answer (score 11):

Metallophone (glockenspiel?) with missing key.

*The Sensory Garden*, Jephson Gardens, Leamington Spa, Warwickshire UK, May 2018.

[image]

Comment: This post and your username fit well together

Comment: This is not a xylophone. Xylophone has wooden bars by definition. This is rather a kind of glockenspiel.

Comment: @Zeus you're right, _xylo_, - wood, _phone_ - sound; but in colloquially, people seem to gravitate towards xylophone as a description for almost all keyboard-like percussion played with mallets. (Don't get me wrong, it drives me nuts when people call a marimba a xylophone, but they just don't know better)  =)

Comment: I really like the composition of this photo. I think it embodies the theme perfectly. (To be fair, as a former percussionist, this hit close to home for me. So I might have been biased towards it).

Comment: @Zeus - Edited. Thanks - lazy terminology on my part.

Comment: @scottbb - Many thanks [but Shh! It's cropped]. Is hitting close to home the definition of a neighbourhood percussionist?

Comment: Cropping is part of making the perfect composition. To paraphrase Ansel Adams, the raw file is the score, the final image is the performance.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Alice Chalmers Loader in snow. Feb 5 2011

Polaroid Type55 negative shot with Pinhole camera.

Contact printed, Lith Print.

Straight scan of the print, B&W 5x7 silver gelatin paper. ( no post production coloring.)

Comment: Sweet detail with the perf sheet!

Answer (score 7):

Incomplete.

07/01/2020, Rome.

[image]

[enter link description here](https://i.ibb.co/PWp6mFc/DSC-0502edit2.jpg)

Comment: what's the problem with this photo?  it is not correct to put -1 without a justified reason.

Comment: Yeap, and the rules say that no voting down on posts.

I edited the post to show the photo. There is a chance that was the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Thank you very much, the photo is not seen directly each time I use my stack app :(

Comment: I upvoted to offset the downvote. Nice pic.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice photo! But I do not understand the date. That’s in 4 days.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote 02 instead of 01!

Comment: Aww.... and I was so impressed that you'd managed to take a picture in the future... :)

Answer (score 7):

**Imperfect Cyclamen Flower**

[image: Imperfect Cyclamen Flower]

A dying flower captured with Olympus E-520, legacy OM 50mm f1.8 lens and 20mm extension tube, two flash one lighting a white background.

> 1/40sec f8 iso400

Answer (score 6):

[image]A shopping trolly dumped in a pond
Northampton, UK. 06/02/2020

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Industrial remnants. Arts District, LA. July 23rd 2019

Answer (score 1):

A bar at Hotel Valcartier, in Quebec, Canada. 12/21/2019
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Non-Starter, Mayence, 02/08/2020]

Non-Starter, Mayence, 02/08/2020

Station clock that seems to have a broken flourescent starter - the illumination looks like it is from the start phase of the flourescent tube, giving much weaker and also very different lighting (allowing the architectural detail to not be blacked out completely).

A7s, ISO 20000, 1/160s, Leitz 180mm/f3.4 wide open, too little time to perfect it since there were rowdy persons around....