# Photo competition May 2020: Lomography

Tags: photo-competition

#### Theme

After another delay, I've decided to take the initiative to start another photo competition here.

The theme for this competition is "**Lomography**". The challenge is to post the best picture that would fall short of "professional" photographic standards. For example, photos taken on old or cheap digital cameras that have low resolution, photos taken on long-expired film, or photos which exhibit significant "mistakes" such as light leaks. For more information, see the [Wikipedia article on lomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_camera#Lomography).

<sub>For clarity, the word "lomography" refers to the genre of photography, not to the photographic brand [Lomography](https://lomography.com/). Photos submitted need not necessarily be taken on Lomography-brand equipment.</sub>

#### Voting Rules

- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **upvotes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote. If you believe an image doesn't meet the guidelines, comment on it or bring it up in chat.
- **Voting closes on June 1, 2020 at 00:00 UTC**. The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time

#### Submission rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Multiple entries are encouraged, but please don't spam answers. The aim is quality over quantity.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date.** It's also recommended to include the equipment on which they were taken and any other info about the image. (I'm personally curious to know.)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike [2.5](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/), [3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), or [4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), depending on the time it was uploaded to the site.
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

- Suggest a theme for a future contest. Leave a single comment below in the format,

  > Theme: <*one sentence description*>
- Upvote the comment(s) with the theme you would like to see later.

Good luck!

<sub>Competition rules taken from [scottbb's prior photo competition series here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/114433/77292). The theme was my idea, and I [ran it by them](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54357822#54357822) before posting this.</sub>

Comment: Theme: COVID-19

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Paris Auto show 2001]

Audi on turntable, @Paris Auto show 2001,

Camera:[Zero Image 4x5 Pinhole camera](http://www.zeroimage.com/Pinhole_Camera_45_2015.html), 4x5 film, Lith Print, Black & White Silver Gelatin, Straight scan of print ( no post color added.)

I do not remember details, I wanna say Ilford HP5 ?  @ 30 seconds to one minute exposure, tripod on the turntable with the car.

Comment: Congratulations on winning the photo contest! Can you please let me know what title you'd like used, for your featuring on the sidebar?

Comment: Title: Audi-Go-Round

Answer (score 6):

[image: Calico Cat]

Taken on a Minolta 35mm film camera circa 1980. The image was transferred from negative to digital in 2008. Colors are faded, resolution is crap, but it is still an interesting photo to me.

Answer (score 4):

[image: fog at Wicksteed]
Taken at Wicksteed Park, Kettering, Northamptonshire. January 2018.
An early 2mb digital Panasonic camera. Now no longer in existence, but it was a point and shoot! 
Some additional editing later

Comment: Sorry, the photo competition has closed to votes. We have already chosen a photo to feature from the ones previously submitted.

Comment: I love this photo.